# Downloading software within ubuntu

Tags: installation

When I go into Ubuntu Software center and download software it will say download complete but when i search for it on the pc to open it its nowhere to be found, I figured it would go into dash home but its nowhere to be found. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which software? Have you tried typing the software's name in the search bar on the dash?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `whereis` command?

Syntax is `$whereis 'software name u r looking for'`

Here's an example :

```
$ whereis unity
unity: /usr/bin/unity /usr/lib/unity /usr/share/unity /usr/share/man/man1/unity.1.gz
```